# Can I use separate database for phpunit integration tests of crons?

Tags: magento2, phpunit

Sometimes I want to ensure that for some cases that records are written correctly upon database mostly in cron for bulk actions that read records from one table and written into another table for example this cron job:

```
namespace Pcmagas\PhpUnitLearnModule\Cron;

use Pcmagas\PhpUnitLearnModule\Model\Factories\CustomerEmail\CollectionFactory;
use \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface;

class SetCustomersToDefaultCustomerGroup
{
    private CollectionFactory $factory;

    private ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig;

    public function __construct(
        CollectionFactory $factory,
        ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
    ) {
        $this->factory = $factory;
        $this->scopeConfig=$scopeConfig;
    }

   
    public function execute()
    {
        /**
         * @var $collection \MageGuide\CustomerEmails\Model\ResourceModel\CustomerEmail\Collection
         */
        $collection = $this->factory->create();
        $table = $collection->getMainTable();
        /**
         * @var $resource \Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql\Interceptor
         */
        $resource = $collection->getConnection();

        // @todo use magento's config.
        $default_customer_group=(int)$this->scopeConfig->getValue("default_group_id/myplugin/default_group_id");

        /**
         * Emails where the group id will be changed
         * @var Magento\Framework\DB\Select
         */
        $select = $resource->select()
            ->from($table,'emails')
            ->join('customer_entity',$table.".email=customer_entity.email")
            ->where("customer_entity.group_id <> $table.customer_group_id")
            ->columns([$table.'.email']);

        $queryResults = $resource->fetchAll($select);


        try {
            $resource->beginTransaction();
            foreach($queryResults as $email){
                if(empty($emails)){
                    continue ;
                }
                $resource->update(
                    'customer_entity',
                    ['group_id'=>$default_customer_group],
                    [
                        'email '=>$email
                    ]
                );
            }
            $resource->commit();
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $resource->rollBack();
        }
    }
}
```

In my case I have 2 tables:

1. One that has the email list
2. The customer_entity table

And I want to write a test that checks that emails will be written correctly. Usually upon php projects I mock everything EXCEPT the database, especially in laravel. Usually what I do is either at `phpunit.xml` or at .env.testing I set the testing database credentials that are used instead ones from the normal installation.

So is there an approach where I can configure a separate - test only database at magento. And setup the necessary schema with necessary modules only (disabling the ones not needed for testing)?